# What is a symmetry?

Tags: geometry

I'm reading The Princeton Companion to Mathematics, and in it I see this passage:

> If S is a geometrical shape, then a rigid motion of S is a way of moving S in such a way that the distances between the points of S are not changed—squeezing and stretching are not allowed. A rigid motion is a sym- metry of S if, after it is completed, S looks the same as it did before it moved. For example, if S is an equilateral triangle, then rotating S through 120◦ about its center is a symmetry; so is reflecting S about a line that passes through one of the vertices of S and the midpoint of the opposite side.
> 19
> More formally, a symmetry of S is a function f from S to itself such that the distance between any two points x and y of S is the same as the distance between the transformed points f (x) and f (y).

Isn't this "formal definition" actually the definition of a rigid motion: distances don't change after transformation? Wouldn't a correct definition be f(S)=S (the image of the set of the shape's coordinates is the same as the original coordinates) meaning a prism, for example, when rotated a certain angle keeps its original coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your doubt correctly, but "a symmetry of S is a function f from S *to itself*" is the key part which seems to implement your expectations. Any arbitrary rigid motion does not have this property because it possibly moves $S$ somewhere else.

Comment: This is certainly not a formal definition. Nothing is formally mathematically defined. The goal is to give intuitive meanings.

Comment: A rigid motion isn't a symmetry, if, say, it shifts $S$ three inches to the left. And $f(S)=S$ doesn't give a symmetry, since it need not be a rigid motion.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek So is the "such that the distance between any two points x and y of S is the same as the distance between the transformed points f (x) and f (y)." part unnecessary? That seems to be the rigid motion definition. Is it possible for a non-rigid motion to be a symmetry (i.e. one of the faces is weirdly stretched but still looks the same)?

Comment: There is an attempt here to capture the notion of symmetry and it defines a symmetry as a particular kind of rigid motion. There is also an abstract definition of symmetry via the action of a Group on a Set, which may involve non-rigid transformations (so they are not necessarily what we would understand as symmetries in concrete geometric terms).

Comment: The other part (preserving distances) is also necessary. It must be a rigid motion of the shape onto exactly itself, if you want to use such terms.

Comment: You should not use this book as a source for rigorous learning of mathematics. It is a mere glimpse of various math concepts, involving some vigorous handwaving. It is useful, however, if you have never seen some of the math concepts they discuss in order to get **some** idea of the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the initial part of the cited text, a symmetry is a transformation with two properties:

1. It's a rigid motion, so it preserves lengths.
2. It transforms the shape $S$ into itself. So for every point of the shape, the transformed point is also on the shape, and conversely every point of the shape is the transformation result of some point on the shape.

So what you probably expected to read is something that takes a function satisfying condition 1 and then checks condition 2. “A rigid motion is a symmetry if it transforms the shape to itself.” The book does it the other way round, thought: “A function that transforms the shape to itself is a symmetry if it preserves lengths.” Both are correct and essentially the same thing.

The only problem I have with the formulation is that the function is *to* $S$ itself, not *onto* $S$. So it's missing a clear statement of surjectivity. Furthermore, one probably would expect the function to be defined outside the shape as well. So the invariance of $S$ could have been written more clearly, and $f(S)=S$ would have been better.

Note that “symmetry” may be defined differently in different contexts. Some only consider reflections. Some don't require isometry. Some would consider e.g. a circle inversion to be a form of symmetry if it maps a shape onto itself. It depends on context. Requiring a rigid motion is probably the most common definition, but not the only one.